# Functional variation of potential in integral form

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle

I am trying to vary the following action, 
$$
S=\int_{t_0}^{t_1} \text{d}t\,(v^\mu v^\nu g_{\mu\nu} + V(t)) =\int_{t_0}^{t_1}\text{d}t\,(v^\mu v^\nu g_{\mu\nu} + \int_{t_0}^t\text{d}s T_\mu v^\mu)
$$
where $v^\mu$ is the four momentum, and $g_{\mu\nu}$ depends on the coordinates.

Now, if I consider variation of such an action I need to be able to compute 
$$
\delta \left (\int_{t_0}^{t_1}\text{d}t\int_{t_0}^t\text{d}s T_\mu v^\mu\right )
$$
Clearly this is not zero, since if I write $T_\mu = \partial_\mu \theta$, i
get 
$$
\delta \left (\int_{t_0}^{t_1}\text{d}t\int_{t_0}^t\text{d}s T_\mu v^\mu\right ) = \delta \left (\int_{t_0}^{t_1}\text{d}t\theta(x(t)) - \textit{ const}\right ) = \int_{t_0}^{t_1}\text{d}t \partial_\mu \theta \delta x^\mu
$$
where I used the fact that 
$$v^\mu = \frac{\text{d}x^\mu}{\text{d}t}$$
But in the more general case (in which $\partial_{[\mu}T_{\nu]}\neq 0$) I don't know how to compute the variation, any suggestions?

Comment: Comment to the post (v2): 1. The four momentum looks more like a four velocity.